# Installing browsercap.ini

Tags: php

I'm on `Hostmonster` running Linux and I want to install the browsercap.ini on my server which I have installed on the main `public_html` directory with the file name as `php_browsercap.ini` and I have set it into my original php.ini here:

```
[browscap]
; http://php.net/browscap
browscap = php_browscap.ini
```

However it doesn't work when I work with `get_browser()` since I get:

> Warning: get_browser() [function.get-browser]: browscap ini directive not set

This is my `phpinfo()` for what I get with `browsercap`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you should specify absolute path to browscap.ini in your PHP INI